# How do I update the URL upon changes in the Place in GWT?

Tags: gwt

I have a CellTable, containing a huge amount of data. Above the tables, the user can add different types of filters, limiting the amount of displayed data.

Every time one of these filters are changed, it is reflected in the Place. 
I have developed a BasePlace, that handles adding and removing subtokens from the place. This results in the following URL (given by Tokenizer.getToken()):

```
mysite.com/#ShowCellTable:Filter1=a,b,c&Filter2=123
```

In this case with two filters, Filter1 is configured with data ‘a,b,c’ and Filter2 is configured with data ‘123’

The filters modifies the place with the given filter and filter configuration values.

This works semi-great. I can enter the url in to the browser, and my app displays the correct filters with correct configuration. However when configuring the filters by entering the filter values above the CellTable, the values are correctly written to the Place, but the Place is not reflected in the URL.
If however, I navigate away from the CellTable page, and navigate back again (placeController.goTo(cellTablePlace)) - the URL will correctly display the values stored in the Place.

What shall I do in order to let the token stored in the Place (and fetched by the Tokenizer.getToken()) be reflected in the URL, when modifying the filters directly on the page?

Thanx

---

**Update (2017.02.13):**

I still haven't found a solution to my problem...

Changing the Place for an app might be due to two different causes:

1. The user navigates away from the current Place
2. The user changes some parameters on the current page (this is what I am trying to do)

If he user navigates away from the current place (1), it is programmatically done by calling goTo on the PlaceController:

```
placeController.goTo(new MyPlace(token));
```

... where token represents the parameters for the new place.

If I want to change the filter parameters for the current page (2), then my first thought was just to call goTo on the PlaceController with the new filter parameters. However, this does not work, since an if statement in the PlaceController checks, if the new place is the same as the old one:

```
public void goTo(Place newPlace) {
  log().fine("goTo: " + newPlace);

  if (getWhere().equals(newPlace)) {
    log().fine("Asked to return to the same place: " + newPlace);
    return;
  }

  String warning = maybeGoTo(newPlace);
  if (warning == null || delegate.confirm(warning)) {
    where = newPlace;
    eventBus.fireEvent(new PlaceChangeEvent(newPlace));
  }
}
```

If however, I simply call the eventBus directly, nothing happens. I have found, that this is because at this point in the code, there are no eventhandlers attached, that could handle the code...

Any help?

---

**Update (2017.02.20):**

I have now found the answer to my own question.

First, I found an error in my code: I had instantiated two instances of my ClientFactory, resulting in two instances of the EventBus. Which was the reason, why nothing happened, when sending events on the EventBus.

However, firing an event on the EventBus now caused 3 AttachDetachException's.

I fixed this, by deferring the call to the EventBus:

```
void filterChanged() {
    Scheduler.get().scheduleDeferred(this::deferredRefreshPlace);
}

private void deferredRefreshPlace() {
    clientFactory.getEventBus().fireEvent(new PlaceChangeEvent(place));
}
```